# i want to upload to 2gb model animation to vram with VBO technic but i am getting this error with nvidia (with amd no error)

Tags: opengl

[image]

when i try to work with amd its working with amd hd6870 and ati x1550 but when i try to work with gtx 950 its giving this error. if i upload less than 2gb example 300mb then its working but i want to upload 2gb. what can i do ? sorry for bad english.

Comment: downsize your animation model to be below 2 gig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the GTX 950 has only 2GB of RAM.

[image]

The Nvidia driver/architecture may not allow active datasets to be partially contained in system RAM.

You're also trying to allocate over 2GB of virtual memory total in a 32bits program on a 64bits windows system that is limited to 2GB per 32bits process.

32bits windows can accommodate 3GB per 32bits process, 64bits windows is limited to 2GB per 32bits process.

Rebuild your project as a 64bits application and try again.